# unzip a file into /tmp folder using lambda function from s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a bucket by the name "testing_lambda".  Also within this "temp_lambda" folder, it stored a zip file named "test.zip".

I wish to use lambda function to first read the file from that bucket folder and then unzip it to a /tmp folder within the lambda function before continue other process but I just cant make it work.

I cant even try the simplest code by accessing the resource. I am wondering whether is there anyone can assist me.

Code:

```
import boto3

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': s3_resource.buckets.all()
    }
```

Error:

```
  "errorMessage": "Unable to marshal response: s3.bucketsCollection(s3.ServiceResource(), s3.Bucket) is not JSON serializable",
```

Edited:
unzip-requirement.py

```
import os
import shutil
import sys
import zipfile
import boto3
import io

pkgdir = '/tmp/sls-py-req'

sys.path.append(pkgdir)

s3_resource = boto3.resource("s3")

bucket = "testing_lambda"
key = ".test.zip"
response = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket)
obj = response.Object(key)

with io.BytesIO(obj.get()["Body"].read()) as tf:
    if not os.path.exists(pkgdir):
        tempdir = '/tmp/_temp-sls-py-req'
        if os.path.exists(tempdir):
            shutil.rmtree(tempdir)
    
        default_layer_root = '/opt'
        lambda_root = os.getcwd() if os.environ.get('IS_LOCAL') == 'true' else default_layer_root
        zip_requirements = os.path.join(lambda_root, key)
    
        zipfile.ZipFile(zip_requirements, 'r').extractall(tempdir)
        os.rename(tempdir, pkgdir)  # Atomic
```

lambda_function.py
This python is use to test whether I could import torch.

```
try:
    import unzip_requirements
except ImportError:
    pass
import json
import torch

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    d = {"torch": torch.__version__}
    return json.dumps(d)
```

Current error:

```
START RequestId: e15cdba6-6167-448b-adb0-b52379ab563a Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] NoSuchKey: An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 234, in load_module
    return load_source(name, filename, file)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 2, in <module>
    import unzip_requirements
  File "/var/task/unzip_requirements.py", line 19, in <module>
    with io.BytesIO(obj.get()["Body"].read()) as tf:
  File "/var/runtime/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 520, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/boto3/resources/action.py", line 83, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(*args, **params)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 676, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
END RequestId: e15cdba6-6167-448b-adb0-b52379ab563a
REPORT RequestId: e15cdba6-6167-448b-adb0-b52379ab563a  Duration: 1478.68 ms    Billed Duration: 1479 ms    Memory Size: 516 MB Max Memory Used: 36 MB  
Unknown application error occurred
```

Comment: How are you triggering this function? Do you want it to run when the file is uploaded, or are you just running it manually?

Comment: Hi, i edited my questions and included more info.

Comment: It should be `key = 'temp_lambda/test.zip'`

Comment: Thank you but I still receive the same error.

Comment: In that case, the object does not exist. You can test things by running the code on your local machine, rather than in a Lambda function. Once that works, convert it to Lambda. You can also run `aws cp s3://testing_lambda/temp_lambda/test.zip ./` to try copying the file to your local computer, to confirm that the path is correct.

Answer (score 1):

`s3_resource.buckets.all()` returns an iterator, which can't be easily converted into JSON. If you wish to debug the contents, then you should loop through the results and print information, such as:

```py
for bucket in s3_resource.buckets.all():
  print(bucket.name)
```

Your program will need to:

- Download the file to the `/tmp/` directory
- Unzip the file
- Process the unzipped file

There is no need for your Lambda function to return anything unless your invocation code is expecting a result.

Comment: thank you and I also edited my questions, it shows what I wanted to do. if you could please check it too.

Answer (score 0):

The tmp folder has limited memory and it might throw errors later. Instead, you should read your zip files into a buffer, then extract all filenames. Then iterate through all the files within the zip folder, read each one individually and then upload to your desired s3 folder.

```
        buffer = BytesIO(zipped_file.get()["Body"].read())
        zipped = zipfile.ZipFile(buffer)
        
        for file in zipped.namelist():
            logger.info(f'current file in zipfile: {file}')
            final_file_path = file + '.extension'

            with zipped.open(file, "r") as f_in:
                content = f_in.read()
                destinationbucket.upload_fileobj(io.BytesIO(content),
                                                        final_file_path,
                                                        ExtraArgs={"ContentType": "text/plain"}
                                                )
```

There's a detailed tutorial here: https://betterprogramming.pub/unzip-and-gzip-incoming-s3-files-with-aws-lambda-f7bccf0099c9